# Avoiding SQL Injection

Tags: java, sql-injection, security

I want to avoid SQL Injections in my Webapp.
It's Java based.

Are PreparedStatements enough?

Do i have to filter out the ' and "? Are there already solutions for this in Java?

Answer (score 5):

My gut response to the question in your second paragraph is that it's usually a bad idea to consider a single aspect "enough" for this sort of issue - at least if you do this to the point that you stop thinking about the principles involved.

Using PreparedStatements does go a long way to stopping SQL injection, just like using slapping down `synchronized` everywhere goes a long way to stopping data races.  And in many individual situations they'll be entirely sufficient.  But in both cases they're not magic bullets - you need to be aware of the reasons you're using them, and when and where they're insufficient.  For example, if you think PreparedStatements are a magic wrapper that prevents SQL injection, you'll be very disappointed the first time you need to create a dynamic statement (as opposed to merely a parameterised one) based on user input.

Thus the thing that's "enough", is education.  Understand how and why the threat works; once you grok that, you'll be able to take the appropriate actions to a given situation (which sometimes is just using a PreparedStatement, but not always).  I'm not aware of any particularly good resources on SQL injection though (above and beyond what you can get from Google), so hopefully other answers can point you to the One True Tutorial!

Answer (score 4):

Simply never craft your SQLs manually by concatenating Strings, always use `PreparedStatement` and parameterize it with `?` wildcards. JDBC driver will take care of escaping, so you don't have to do it yourself.

On the other hand **escaping is hard**. You would be surprised how many ways there are to work around your escaping algorithms. JDBC driver will do the job properly.

Answer (score 2):

Although Prepared Statements helps in defending against SQL Injection, there are possibilities of SQL Injection attacks through inappropriate usage of Prepared Statements. The example below explains such a scenario where the input variables are passed directly into the Prepared Statement and thereby paving way for SQL Injection attacks.

Example:

```
String strUserName = request.getParameter("Txt_UserName"); 
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userId = '+strUserName+'");
```

More information on preventing SQL injections [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java).

---

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/) is a great place to start for anything security related to software development. 
They have java libraries which you can use to prevent XSS and SQL injections.

They also have a webapp which is very unsecure, which you can try to hack, and by that learn how **not** to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statements *can* be enough. If using prepared statements you still have to take care of building the statements with wildcards only. In other words, it's possible to use prepared statements the wrong way. You do not have to filter out any parameters to avoid SQL injection. Nevertheless, you may need to filter out certain values to avoid web based attacks (like XSS), depends on your environment and scope.